# Lagom - how to post a x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: lagom, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have a service locator, which link to external URL. Then I want to `invoke` that service inside my implementation.

here is the idea, in my build.sbt, I put the URL of my service

```
lagomUnmanagedServices in ThisBuild := Map(
  "Foo" -> "https://www.xxxxxx.com"
)
```

And then, I have the service with the exact name

```
trait FooService extends Service {
  override final def descriptor: Descriptor = {
    import Service._
    named("Foo")
      .withCalls(
        restCall(Method.POST, "/PostUrl", fooServiceCall _)
          .withRequestSerializer(???)
      )
      .withAutoAcl(true)
  }


def fooServiceCall(): ServiceCall[FooRequest, FooResponse]
```

Then I can just call this service/ api by invoking it

```
fooService.fooServiceCall.invoke()
```

but the problem is, the request that I sent should be formatted into `x-www-form-urlencoded` rather than a normal `Json` format. Is it possible to achieve this?

*PS. the response still come in a normal `Json` format

Answer (score 2):

Only needs to add the serialization to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` for your `FooRequest` case class, following the instructions from [Lagom documentation](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/scala/MessageSerializers.html)

First Step: Create Negotiated Serializer and Deserializer for `FooRequest` and `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
class FooUrlEncodedSerializer extends NegotiatedSerializer[FooRequest, ByteString] {
  override val protocol = MessageProtocol(Some("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
  
  // Convert your FooRequest in a ByteString following the format of urlencoded protocol
  // "field1=value1;field2=value2;..." 
  def serialize(fooRequest: FooRequest) =
    ByteString.fromString(...)
}

class FooUrlEncodedDeserializer extends NegotiatedDeserializer[FooRequest, ByteString] {
  // Convert a ByteString urlencoded in a FooRequest object
  def deserialize(bytes: ByteString): FooRequest = {...}
}
```

Second Step: Create the MessageSerializer to be used in your call

```
class FooRequestFormUrlEncodedSerializer extends StrictMessageSerializer[FooRequest] {
  override def serializerForRequest: NegotiatedSerializer[FooRequest, ByteString] = new FooUrlEncodedSerializer

  override def deserializer(protocol: MessageProtocol): MessageSerializer.NegotiatedDeserializer[FooRequest, ByteString] = new FooUrlEncodedDeserializer

  override def serializerForResponse(acceptedMessageProtocols: Seq[MessageProtocol]): NegotiatedSerializer[FooRequest, ByteString] = new FooUrlEncodedSerializer
}
```

Final Step: Add the serializer to your service descriptor:

```
trait FooService extends Service {
  override final def descriptor: Descriptor = {
    import Service._
    named("Foo")
      .withCalls(
        restCall(Method.POST, "/PostUrl", fooServiceCall _)
          .withRequestSerializer(new FooRequestFormUrlEncodedSerializer)
      )
      .withAutoAcl(true)
  }

def fooServiceCall(): ServiceCall[FooRequest, FooResponse]
```

Since you want to receive the response as Json, you don't need to generate a Message Serializer for your FooResponse object.