# How to generate token and send mail notification with graph api using scala

Tags: java, scala, microsoft-graph-api

How can I generate a graph api token using scala code. I have tried with python using below code I am able to generate. But I didn't found for scala.

```
import requests
import sys
import os
import json

TOKEN_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/bgd57sd-dsd-4b9d-b9c5-0f64b6755421/oauth2/token"
EMAIL_URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ssr_etl_np@gh.com/sendMail"

# generate oauth access_token
def get_access_token(url):
    payload = "client_id=" + os.getenv("AD_APP_ID") + \
        "&client_secret=" + os.getenv("AD_APP_SECRET") + \
        "&grant_type=client_credentials" + \
        "&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com"
    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    resp = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    return resp.json()["access_token"]

access_token = get_access_token(TOKEN_URL)
```

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. What documentation are you trying to follow, what is the error message, what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

As graph token API accepts form-URL-encoded data so you should implement a separate encoderSerilizer.scala class
please refer to below link
[Lagom - how to post a x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480362/lagom-how-to-post-a-x-www-form-urlencoded)
then
restCall(Method.POST, "/xyz/oauth2/v2.0/token", getAuthToken).withRequestSerializer(new FormUrlEncodedSerializer)

Comment: Thanks, I want to call api from databricks, Is there any option like request library in python.

Comment: @Suvam Banerjee, Can you pls help me with how the access token is generating? Thanks